# My screen glitches out when I try to run my subprogram code

Tags: python, pygame

[image]I'm working on a subprogram code that will make this happy face bounce around the screen and turn different colours. For some reason, the screen turns into that black glitchy screen and when I press exit at the top the face shows for a quick second before the program shuts down. I can't figure out why this is, here is my code and I've included a picture of what happens at first when I run it:

```
""" Program to show a very basic function
    Most of the program is exactly the same as other programs we have done
    The main difference is the grouping of code into a function called
    drawHappy() to draw a few shapes together
    In the main loop we "call" this function whenever we want to draw this
    group of shapes
"""


# import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random
from random import randint

# initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# set the size for the surface (screen)
# note this screen is resizable by the user
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Happy Face")

#screen width and height
screenW = screen.get_width()
screenH = screen.get_height()

# define colours you will be using
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# funtion to draw a the "happy face"
# it has 4 parameters passed to it xPos, yPos, radius, and colour
# notice all the shapes are drawn "relative" to the xPos and yPos and the radius
def drawHappy(xPos,yPos,r,colour):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(xPos,yPos),r,1)
    eyeRadius = int(1/6*r)
    eyeX = int(xPos-1/3*r)
    eyeY = int(yPos- 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    eyeX = int(xPos + 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    wMouth = 1.5*r
    xMouth = xPos - 3/4*r
    yMouth = yPos - 3/4*r
    pygame.draw.arc(screen,colour,(xMouth,yMouth,wMouth,wMouth),math.pi,2*math.pi,1)



randomR = randint(1,300)
r = randomR

randomX = randint(r, 800-r)
randomY = randint(r, 600-r)

dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 100
y = 100
speed = 3
x2 = randomX
y2 = randomY
dx2 = speed
dy2 = -speed

colour_list = [YELLOW, BLACK, BLUE, RED, GREEN]
randomcolour = random.choice(colour_list)
colour = RED 
# set up clock to control frames per second
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 120

# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop

    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

oldx = x
oldy = y
x += dx
y += dy

if x >= 800-r or x <= 0+r:
    x = oldx
if y >= 600-r or y <= 0+r:
    y = oldy

x2 += dx2
y2 += dy2

if x >= 800-r or x <= 0+r:
    dx2 = -dx2
    randomcolour = random.choice(colour_list)
    colour = randomcolour
if y2 >= 600-r or y2 <= 0+r:
    dy2 = -dy2
    randomcolour = random.choice(colour_list)
    colour = randomcolour




    # "call" the function "drawHappy()" to draw the happy face
    # this is where we would normally do a pygame.draw or a screen.blit()
    # we are "passing" the function 4 values to use(x,y,radius, colour)
    # it will use these to know where to draw the happy face
drawHappy(x2,y2,r,colour)

pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Mind showing a screenshot/whatever of the issue?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I've included a photo now, thank you

Comment: You are not drawing anything in your main loop.  You only draw the face after the loop has terminated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to call your `draw function` inside the loop. Your current code shows only a glimpse of "drawing" because it gets executed once you exit the main loop.
So, put your `drawHappy()` inside of main loop:

```
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop

    drawHappy(x2,y2,r,colour)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
```

Now you will get a random size "smiley" on the screen, But now it will move on exit only, for the same reason it wouldn't display earlier. Next thing is to make it bounce (move). For this you'll need some kind of update of the coordinates, just like you did in the last part of your code, except they also need to be updated during the loop, not after it.

I suggest making a `Class` because then it will be easier to manipulate the object.

Also, I found it easier to separate `draw` and `update_coordinates` code into separate functions and them call them from main loop for example.
Hope this helps, and if you need more help, ask.

Here, I made a quick solution using parts of your code, there is plenty room for improvement especially for `update_smiley_position()` method where you can control how "smiley" moves.
Also, if you need multiple objects, a list should be passed instead of single object.

```
import pygame as pg
import math
import random

pg.init()

clock = pg.time.Clock()

window = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600), pg.RESIZABLE)
pg.display.set_caption("Happy Face")

SCREEN_W = window.get_width()
SCREEN_H = window.get_height()


class Smiley:

    def __init__(self, x, y, r, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.color = color
        self.create_smiley()

    def create_smiley(self):
        self.eye_radius = int(1/6 * self.r)
        self.eye_x1 = int(self.x - 1/3 * self.r)
        self.eye_x2 = int(self.x + 1/3 *self.r)
        self.eye_y = int(self.y - 1/3 *self.r)
        self.mouth_width = 1.5 * self.r
        self.mouth_x = self.x - self.r * 0.75
        self.mouth_y = self.y - self.r * 0.75

    def draw_smiley(self, win):
        pg.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.r, 1)
        pg.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.eye_x1, self.eye_y), self.eye_radius, 1)
        pg.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.eye_x2, self.eye_y), self.eye_radius, 1)
        pg.draw.arc(win, self.color, (self.mouth_x, self.mouth_y, self.mouth_width, self.mouth_width), math.pi, 2*math.pi, 1)

    def update_smiley_position(self):

        if self.x >= SCREEN_H - self.r or self.x <= 0 + self.r:
            self.x = random.randint(100, 400)
        else:
            self.x += 5

        if self.y >= SCREEN_W - self.r or self.y <= 0 + self.r:
            self.y = random.randint(100, 400)
        else:
            self.y -= 5

        self.create_smiley()



def draw(win, smiley):

    win.fill(pg.Color("white"))
    smiley.draw_smiley(win)
    smiley.update_smiley_position()


    pg.display.update()


def main_loop(win, smiley):

    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            return False

    draw(win, smiley)

    return True


r = random.randint(1, 300)
x = random.randint(r, SCREEN_W - r)
y = random.randint(r, SCREEN_H - r)

smiley = Smiley(x, y, r, pg.Color("red"))

while main_loop(window, smiley):
    pass


pg.quit()
```